# Clicking "Send message" button when replying to job messages opens file browser

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, firefox, jobs-messages

When responding to a message in my inbox and click "send message", it opens the *attach file* dialog.

My workaround was to set the style of the attach file button to `display:none`.

I'm using Firefox 65.0.1 on MacOS.

[image: The Send Message and Attach File buttons are right below a box for typing in a message.]

Comment: I had this same problem in Safari and Chrome on MacOS and Chrome on Windows.  Used a similar work around.  The clickable area for the File Upload button extends from the right side of the "Attach File" styled button to the left side of the window, completely covering the Send Message submit button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're working on improvements to the messaging interface. It would appear there were some styling conflicts happening that increased the click area of the "attach file" button, overlapping the "send message" button.

This should now be resolved.